# variable not showing up in bash script when using an array

Tags: bash

I have a script to prepare some files to submit trough `qsub` to a cluster, I am creating an array based on a file and then using the elements in that array to create my qsub files.
However, I can't append the variables to the `$RawData/$i_1.fastq.gz` part. This is my script:

```
> cat create.sh
#!/bin/bash

 RawData="/home/jfertaj/data/FASTQ" 

 # make an array of each sample id 
 mapfile -t myArray < array.txt

 for i in "${myArray[@]}"
 do
      cat > pbs.script.$i << EOF
 #!/bin/bash

 kallisto quant -t 16 -b 100 -o /home/jfertaj/data/results_kallisto/output_bootstrap_$i $RawData/$i_1.fastq.gz $RawData/$i_2.fastq.gz

 EOF
 done
 exit 0;
```

when I run the bash script and look the created files I see this:

```
...
kallisto quant -t 16 -b 100 -o /home/jfertaj/data/results_kallisto/output_bootstrap_INTP_993 /home/jfertaj/data/FASTQ/.fastq.gz /home/jfertaj/data/FASTQ/.fastq.gz
```

I have tried including `"$i"` but then this shows up on the resulting files: `"INTP_993"_1.fastq.tz`. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$RawData/$i_1.fastq.gz $RawData/$i_2.fastq.gz` with `$RawData/${i}_1.fastq.gz $RawData/${i}_2.fastq.gz`.

That is, change this:

```
kallisto quant -t 16 -b 100 -o /home/jfertaj/data/results_kallisto/output_bootstrap_$i $RawData/$i_1.fastq.gz $RawData/$i_2.fastq.gz
```

To this:

```
kallisto quant -t 16 -b 100 -o /home/jfertaj/data/results_kallisto/output_bootstrap_$i $RawData/${i}_1.fastq.gz $RawData/${i}_2.fastq.gz
```

The shell treats `i_1` and `i_2` as variable names, when you really want the variable `i` appended with "_1" and "_2". In such situations, when you need to use some variable `somevar` followed by some suffix starting with symbols that are valid in variable names, let's say `_suffix`, you need to use braces to identify the variable. So instead of `$somevar_suffix` you need to write `${somevar}_suffix`.

This is mentioned in `man bash`, emphasis mine:

> ${parameter}
>
> The  value of parameter is substituted.  **The braces are required**
>      when parameter is a positional  parameter  with  more  than  one
>      digit, or **when parameter is followed by a character which is not
>      to be interpreted as part of its name**.  [...]

Answer (score 2):

`_` is a legal character for variable names, so you need to use the full syntax for parameter expansion to keep it from being treated as part of the parameter name. `$i_1.fastq.gz` is interpreted as `${i_1}.fastq.gz`, not `${i}_1.fastq.gz`.

```
for i in "${myArray[@]}"
do
    cat > "pbs.script.$i" << EOF
#!/bin/bash

kallisto quant -t 16 -b 100 \
  -o "/home/jfertaj/data/results_kallisto/output_bootstrap_$i" \
  "$RawData/${i}_1.fastq.gz" \
  "$RawData/${i}_2.fastq.gz"

EOF
done
exit 0
```